# CefSharp Window stays blank on Virtaul Maschine

Tags: c#

I'm currently testing our CefSharp Implementation on a VM but unfortunatly the window stays blank (white) with no content. Does some had the same or similar problem? Is it connected with graphics card or some special graphics driver on the VM? Please help!

Comment: You didn't provide any information. The most likely problem is there's no HTML to display. CefSharp is a wrapper over Chromium. Have you tried using Chrome to open the same URL as your program? If Chrome works, are you sure the application's code is loading the URL?

Comment: problem solved with: settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();

Comment: This sounds like that the GPU is causing this. I would not recommend to use this for productive environment. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/009687f7dd2c3a92e2a77760f951e3bf3558b6cf/CefSharp.Core/CefSettingsBase.cs#L457